# JFlex - Regex for "Arrow"

Tags: regex, jflex

So if I wanted to key in an Arrow character, -->, via JFlex's regex, I'd figure it would just be the string "-->". However, if I attempt this, I always get a Could not match Input error.

```
"-->"   {}
```

Doesn't work. Neither does a combination of escaping certain characters as far as I can tell. I know each of those characters is special in flex, and I know the /-->/ literal way that works in other languages wont in Java.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show us your current code, along with your exact input on which you're trying to test this regex?

Comment: 'A --> a B' was input, and the rule was as shown, using JFlex. The problem I believe was that I wasn't taking into account the white space in the input, and thought it was taking a word at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what do you want to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to find a match for '-->'?  If so, the expression `[\-\-\>]+` fill find that match.

Tested at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html